# android base64 encode and decode in php

Tags: java, php, android, security, base64

hi i'm trying to decode two strings then use the return result (byte[]) then put it in a Biginteger constructor Like this :

```
BigInteger bigInteger1 = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decode(myString1,0));
BigInteger bigInteger2 = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decode(myString2,0));
```

then put this BigIntegers on a **`java.security.KeyFactory`** class to create a **RSAPublicKey** like This :

```
KeyFactory.getInstance(ALG).generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(bigInteger1,bigInteger2));
```

then use my public key to encode a string Like this :

```
public static String encrypt(PublicKey publicKey, String str) {
 Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance(ALG);
            instance.init(1, publicKey);
            Base64.encodeToString(instance.doFinal(str.getBytes()), 2);
}
```

on **PHP**. I achieve this goal with android but when I want to do it with **PHP** I have a lot of problems even on the start when I want to decode my string in **PHP** with this code :

```
$encoded = base64_decode($base,true);
$decoded = utf8_decode(base64_decode($encoded));
```

I will get this string:**??2?]????5N?[??S**

but in android, the decoded string is totally different and always stay the same result

I tried to do this job on **[JSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages)** but it's really hard to learn a new language and I don't have the time.

**Can I do this project in spring boot? I have the codes for java**

please, somebody, help me.

Answer (score 0):

You're decoding string twice. You should try :

```
$encoded = base64_encode($base); // and not base64_decode
$decoded = base64_decode($encoded); // will be $base
```

`utf8_decode` is converting a string with ISO-8859-1 characters encoded with UTF-8 to single-byte ISO-8859-1. Are you sure you're needing it ?

In PHP, you can use [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.intval.php) to performs `BigInteger()` but I'm not sure you won't be facing an integer overflow.

Finally, [OpenSSL library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php) will certainly do the job for key generation and encryption.

Comment: hi still the result of base64 decoding is totally different

Comment: I have a little time left for this project and now i'm trying to learn spring boot to do this on a web application with java do you think its a good idea?

Comment: is $base a valid binary string ? It should explains the trouble if not. You could try an online PHP base 64 encode/decode by copy/paste the $base ouput. Aside this, why are you in need of PHP if going with Spring which is Java based ?

Comment: @Bertand yes its a valid string and its working on Java, i need PHP caus i know the language but i don't know how to work with spring and i should learn it